# VBScript and PSExec

Tags: vbscript

Hi I m having problems reading the output provided by WScript.Shell and PSExec. My goal is to be able to read what PSExec.exe returns as text so I can perform some validation with InStr.

The Code is similar to this:

```
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2
Dim cmdLine, strComputer
strComputer = "\\SomeComputer"

cmdLine = "psexec " & strComputer & " cmd /C " & """RD " & """%PROGRAMFILES%\APPFOLDER""" & " /S /Q | RD " & """%PROGRAMFILES%\COMMON FILES\APPFOLDER""" & " /S /Q | RD " & """%SYSTEMROOT%\temp\APPFOLDER""" & " /S /Q"""

Set WSH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSH.Exec(cmdLine)

    Do While WSH.Status = 0
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop

    Select Case WSH.Status
        Case WshFinished
            strOutput = WSH.StdOut.ReadAll
        Case WshFailed
            strOutput = WSH.StdErr.ReadAll
    End Select

    Wscript.Echo strOutput


    If (InStr(strOutput, "validation text") > 0) Then
        'Do Stuff
    End IF
```

The Problem is that strOutput variable comes always empty and I can't perform text validation using - If (InStr(strOutput, "validation text") > 0)

Any Ideas?

Comment: No one? Any suggestion?

Comment: Read reference: [ExitCode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za76z6hh(v=vs.84).aspx). There is an example showing (maybe _poor_ but  working) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered sending the output from `psexec` to an output file and then reading the output file from your `vbscript`?

```
psexec \\remotemachine command.exe >C:\temp\output.txt 2>&1
```

will execute command.exe and send output from `stdOut` and `stdErr` directly into the file output.txt in C:\temp.  You can amend this for your own command.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions